# handling real time data in python , rolling window

Tags: python, numpy, time

I want to create a function that will read a series of time values from a file (with gaps in the sampling rate,thats the problem) and would read me exactly 200 days and allow me to move through the entire data length,say 10000 day,sort of a rolling window.

I am not sure how to code it. Can I add a statement that calculates the difference between two values of the time variable (x axis) up to when is exactly 200 days?

Or can I somehow write a function that would find the starting value say t0 and  then find the element of the array that is closest to t0 + (interval=) 200 days.

What I have so far is:

```
  f = open(reading the file from directory)

  lines = f.readlines()
  print(len(lines))



  tx = np.array([]) # times 
  y= np.array([])
  interval = 200 # days 



  for li in lines:
     col = li.split()

     t0 = np.array([])
     t1 = np.array([])


     tx = np.append(tx, float(col[0]))
     y= np.append(y, float(col[1]))

  t0 = np.append(t0, np.max(tx))
  t1 = np.append(t1, tx[np.argmin(tx)])

  print(t0,t1)

  days = [t1 + dt.timedelta(days = float(x)) for x in days]
  #y = np.random.randn(len(days))

  # use pandas for convenient rolling function:
  df = pd.DataFrame({"day":tx, "value": y}).set_index("day")

 def closest_value(s):
     if s.shape[0]<2:
         return np.nan
     X = np.empty((s.shape[0]-1, 2))
     X[:, 0] = s[:-1]
     X[:, 1] = np.fabs(s[:-1]-s[-1])
     min_diff = np.min(X[:, 1])
     return X[X[:, 1]==min_diff, 0][0]

df['closest_value'] = df.rolling(window=dt.timedelta(days=200)) 
['value'].apply(closest_value, raw=True)
print(df.tail(5))

Output error: 

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 
'datetime.datetime'
```

Additionally, 
First 10 tx and ty values respectively:

```
 0  0.003372722575018
 0.015239999629557  0.003366515509113
 0.045829999726266  0.003385171061055
 0.075369999743998  0.003385171061055
 0.993219999596477  0.003366515509113
 1.022699999623 0.003378941085299
 1.05217999964952   0.003369617612836
 1.08166999975219   0.003397665493594
 3.0025899996981    0.003378941085299
 3.04120999993756   0.003394537568711
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

# load data in days and y arrays

# ... or generate them:
N = 1000 # number of days
day_min = dt.datetime.strptime('2000-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
day_max = 2000

days = np.sort(np.unique(np.random.uniform(low=0, high=day_max, size=N).astype(int)))
days = [day_min + dt.timedelta(days = int(x)) for x in days]
y = np.random.randn(len(days))

# use pandas for convenient rolling function:
df = pd.DataFrame({"day":days, "value": y}).set_index("day")

def closest_value(s):
    if s.shape[0]<2:
        return np.nan
    X = np.empty((s.shape[0]-1, 2))
    X[:, 0] = s[:-1]
    X[:, 1] = np.fabs(s[:-1]-s[-1])
    min_diff = np.min(X[:, 1])
    return X[X[:, 1]==min_diff, 0][0]

df['closest_value'] = df.rolling(window=dt.timedelta(days=200))['value'].apply(closest_value, raw=True)
print(df.tail(5))
```

Output:

```
               value  closest_value
day                                
2005-06-15  1.668638       1.591505
2005-06-16  0.316645       0.304382
2005-06-17  0.458580       0.445592
2005-06-18 -0.846174      -0.847854
2005-06-22 -0.151687      -0.166404
```

Comment: When I run this code it says ValueError: arrays must all be the same length.

Comment: Thanks! I've changed `y = np.random.randn(N)` to `y = np.random.randn(len(days))`

Comment: I have attempted substituting tx and y into days =  days = [day_min + dt.timedelta(days = int(x)) for x in days] but it says its an inavlid argument for this function. How would this function change if I were to use the variables tx and y as in the code above? Can I still use pandas? Sorry I have never used pandas before and though it would be possible to construct something using solely arrays and lists. Thanks

Comment: Write 10 first values of your tx and y, please

Comment: tx = 0 ty = 0.003372722575018,  
0.015239999629557 0.003366515509113, 
0.045829999726266 0.003385171061055, 
0.075369999743998 0.003385171061055,    
0.993219999596477 0.003366515509113,   
1.022699999623 0.003378941085299,   
1.05217999964952 0.003369617612836
1.08166999975219 0.003397665493594
3.0025899996981 0.003378941085299
3.04120999993756 0.003394537568711

Up to around 7000. Thanks

Comment: tx only 0? It should be an array. Please provide first 10 for tx.

Comment: sorry I will add it above for clarity, not very experienced editing my answer

Comment: so 0.015239999629557 is the partial of the day (24*60*0.015239999629557 ~ 00:22). Right?

Comment: yes.  My data has length of around 7000 days, although sampling is very irregular with periods where I am missing say 30-60 days, hence the need for a rolling window where I could exactly go from 200 to 200 days (I am looking for a periodic behaviour, but that function is working).Many thanks for your time

Comment: Just change `days = [day_min + dt.timedelta(days = int(x)) for x in days]` to `days = [day_min + dt.timedelta(days = float(x)) for x in days]` since your days use floating point.

Comment: Hey Dmitry, please find the adapted code above, I am now getting  the error : TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 
'datetime.datetime'

Answer (score 0):

You could use pandas, set a datetime range and create a while loop to process the data in batches.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Load data into pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(filepath)

# Name columns
df.columns = ['dates', 'num_value']

# Convert strings to datetime
df.dates = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

# Print dates within a 200 day interval and move on to the next interval
i = 0
while i < len(df.dates):
    start = df.dates[i]
    end = start + timedelta(days=200)
    print(df.dates[(df.dates >= start) & (df.dates < end)])
    i += 200
```

If the columns don't have headers, you should omit skiprows:

```
dates     num_value
2004-7-1  1
2004-7-2  5
2004-7-4  8
2004-7-5  11
2004-7-6  17

df = pd.read_table(filepath, sep="\s+", skiprows=1)
```

Comment: Could you please give an example of how would I input my data which is in a .dat file (only two columns)? Same as above can I still use pandas? Also the  x variable (is in days not in the date format). Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can still use pandas. Could you give me an example of the date format you are using? Is it only a list of weekdays (Monday, Tuesday...)?

Comment: Hey I have altered my post so as to include the first 10 inputs for the x values (which is days where for example 0.0.015239999629557 is the partial of the day (24*60*0.015239999629557 ~ 00:22). My y values are just amplitudes.Thanks